# Fetching data from MongoDb with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I am testing one scenario based on Hotel search. 
So I have made 3 model classes, those are Hotel, Room and Availability

Below are the three Model classes we are using.

**Hotel.java**

@Document(collection = "Hotels")
public class Hotel {

```
@Id
private String id;

private String name;

private Long pincode;

@Field("roomCategoryDocs")
private Object roomCategoryDocs;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setPincode(Long pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public Object getRoomCategoryDocs() {
    return roomCategoryDocs;
}

public void setRoomCategoryDocs(Object roomCategoryDocs) {
    this.roomCategoryDocs = roomCategoryDocs;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Hotel [id=%s, name=%s, pincode=%s, roomCategoryDocs=%s]", id, name, pincode,
            roomCategoryDocs);
}
```

}

**Room.java**

@Document(collection = "rooms")
public class Room {

```
@Id
private String id;

private String frontImg;

private String category;

private ObjectId hotelId;

@Field("availabilityDocs")
private Object availabilityDocs;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFrontImg() {
    return frontImg;
}

public void setFrontImg(String frontImg) {
    this.frontImg = frontImg;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public ObjectId getHotelId() {
    return hotelId;
}

public void setHotelId(ObjectId hotelId) {
    this.hotelId = hotelId;
}

public Object getAvailabilityDocs() {
    return availabilityDocs;
}

public void setAvailabilityDocs(Object availabilityDocs) {
    this.availabilityDocs = availabilityDocs;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Room [id=%s, frontImg=%s, category=%s, hotelId=%s, availabilityDocs=%s]", id, frontImg,
            category, hotelId, availabilityDocs);
}
```

}

**Availability.java**

@Document(collection = "rooms")
public class Availability {

```
@Id
private String id;

private ObjectId roomId;

private Integer availability;

private Double rate;

private String date;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ObjectId getRoomId() {
    return roomId;
}

public void setRoomId(ObjectId roomId) {
    this.roomId = roomId;
}

public Integer getAvailability() {
    return availability;
}

public void setAvailability(Integer availability) {
    this.availability = availability;
}

public Double getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(Double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Availability [id=%s, roomId=%s, availability=%s, rate=%s, date=%s]", id, roomId,
            availability, rate, date);
}
```

}

These are stored in two mongodb collections, one for Hotel, another one for Room and availability.

Below we have the method of the Controller Class we are fetching the data from

@GetMapping(value = "/hotel")
    public List getAllHotel() {

```
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("pincode").lt(800080)),
            lookup("rooms", "_id", "hotelId", "roomCategoryDocs"), unwind("roomCategoryDocs", true),
            lookup("rooms", "roomCategoryDocs._id", "roomId", "roomCategoryDocs.availabilityDocs"),
            unwind("roomCategoryDocs", true), 
            group("_id").first("name").as("name").last("pincode").as("pincode").push("roomCategoryDocs").as("roomCategoryDocs")

    );

    // Convert the aggregation result into a List
    AggregationResults<Hotel> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Hotels", Hotel.class);
    List<Hotel> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();

    return result;

}
```

Now while fetching the Hotel data, we are getting all the data with the room and availability.

output we are getting:

```
[
  {
    "id": "59fabce1acd8be143417b101",
    "name": "Elegance",
    "pincode": 700042,
    "availabilityDocs": [
      {
        "id": "59fabe39acd8be143417b103",
        "frontImg": "google.com/1234",
        "category": "Deluxe",
        "hotelId": {
          "timestamp": 1509604577,
          "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
          "processIdentifier": 5172,
          "counter": 1552641,
          "timeSecond": 1509604577,
          "time": 1509604577000,
          "date": 1509604577000
        },
        "availabilityDocs1": [
          {
            "id": "59fabf66acd8be14344a2df3",
            "roomId": {
              "timestamp": 1509604921,
              "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
              "processIdentifier": 5172,
              "counter": 1552643,
              "timeSecond": 1509604921,
              "time": 1509604921000,
              "date": 1509604921000
            },
            "availability": 10,
            "rate": 4000,
            "date": "2017-10-11"
          },
          {
                 "id": "59fae259acd8be264cf4430f",
                  "roomId": {
                         "timestamp": 1509604921,
                            "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
                            "processIdentifier": 5172,
                            "counter": 1552643,
                            "timeSecond": 1509604921,
                            "time": 1509604921000,
                            "date": 1509604921000
                        },
                        "availability": 11,
                        "rate": 4001,
                        "date": "2017-10-12"
                }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But now we are stuck on one issue, which is searching based on the date property.

expected output:

Here we want to get data only from 11-10-2017.

```
  {
    "id": "59fabce1acd8be143417b101",
    "name": "Elegance",
    "pincode": 700042,
    "availabilityDocs": [
      {
        "id": "59fabe39acd8be143417b103",
        "frontImg": "google.com/1234",
        "category": "Deluxe",
        "hotelId": {
          "timestamp": 1509604577,
          "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
          "processIdentifier": 5172,
          "counter": 1552641,
          "timeSecond": 1509604577,
          "time": 1509604577000,
          "date": 1509604577000
        },
        "availabilityDocs1": [
          {
            "id": "59fabf66acd8be14344a2df3",
            "roomId": {
              "timestamp": 1509604921,
              "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
              "processIdentifier": 5172,
              "counter": 1552643,
              "timeSecond": 1509604921,
              "time": 1509604921000,
              "date": 1509604921000
            },
            "availability": 10,
            "rate": 4000,
            "date": "2017-10-11"
          }
}
```

Below is the json collection Example
Hotels Collection:

`{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("59fabce1acd8be143417b101"), "name" : "Elegance", "pincode" : 
    NumberLong(700042), "_class" : "com.lara.mongodb.domain.Hotel" 
}`

Rooms Collection Example:

`{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59fabf66acd8be14344a2df3"),
        "roomId" : ObjectId("59fabe39acd8be143417b103"),
        "availability" : 10,
        "rate" : 4000,
        "date" : "2017-10-11",
        "_class" : "com.lara.mongodb.domain.Availability"
}`

I am open to any kind of suggestion regarding the design and any other ideas you might have as I am new to this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is the Availability entity an embedded document to some collection, or are you writing the results to a separate collection. Also it would help if you could add an json example of how your Hotels and rooms collections look like.

Comment: Hi Alex, we are using only 2 collections i.e Hotels and Rooms. Nothing is embedded in our Collection. I have also added the json example you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you I am a little confused on how you have two entities writing in the same collection. And from the example collections you added, one is missing from what I can tell. But setting this aside. I use your end result as an entry point. So I'm starting from:

```
{
    "id": "59fabce1acd8be143417b101",
    "name": "Elegance",
    "pincode": 700042,
    "availabilityDocs": [
      {
        "id": "59fabe39acd8be143417b103",
        "frontImg": "google.com/1234",
        "category": "Deluxe",
        "hotelId": {
          "timestamp": 1509604577,
          "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
          "processIdentifier": 5172,
          "counter": 1552641,
          "timeSecond": 1509604577,
          "time": 1509604577000,
          "date": 1509604577000
        },
        "availabilityDocs1": [
          {
            "id": "59fabf66acd8be14344a2df3",
            "roomId": {
              "timestamp": 1509604921,
              "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
              "processIdentifier": 5172,
              "counter": 1552643,
              "timeSecond": 1509604921,
              "time": 1509604921000,
              "date": 1509604921000
            },
            "availability": 10,
            "rate": 4000,
            "date": "2017-10-11"
          },
          {
                 "id": "59fae259acd8be264cf4430f",
                  "roomId": {
                         "timestamp": 1509604921,
                            "machineIdentifier": 11327678,
                            "processIdentifier": 5172,
                            "counter": 1552643,
                            "timeSecond": 1509604921,
                            "time": 1509604921000,
                            "date": 1509604921000
                        },
                        "availability": 11,
                        "rate": 4001,
                        "date": "2017-10-12"
                }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

So this is your result after the aggregation you did. Now you only need the room that is available for the `2017-10-11`. But in your result array you get both "2017-10-12" and "2017-10-11".

So if I had the above result you'd have to add the following:

```
{
    $unwind: "$availabilityDocs"
},
{
    $unwind: "$availabilityDocs.availabilityDocs1"
},
{
    $match: {
        "availabilityDocs.availabilityDocs1.date" : "2017-10-11"
        }
}
```

Comment: We are not storing entities inside a single collection. In mongoDb, we refer it as document, We can store different types of documents in a single Collection, that's one of the strengths of a document oriented database.                                                                                               
And about your sugestion, I have already tried this one, but for some reason Spring is unable to recognize '   "$availabilityDocs.availabilityDocs1" ' syntax with unwind and is returning an empty array.

Comment: I am aware of that buddy. There are inconsistencies though in your description. In your spring aggregation you write push("roomCategoryDocs").as("roomCategoryDocs") but you say you get a result with the field name: "availabilityDocs". So check again your description and correct it. If the unwind doesn't work for you in spring, then check the result. It could be that the fields are called differently